# Unable to retrieve checkbox values from a template file

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I have created a checkbox option for a field.

- Category

  - One
  - Two
  - Three
  - Four

This is the code I am using.

```
    {% for key, item in content.field_room_category if key|first != '#' %}
         <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

In the `<li>` tag, I get all the checked values, but I also need to check which values have been selected.

For this, I tried `{{ item.value }}`, `{{ item.content }}`, and `{{ item['#title'] }}`. None of them worked.

Is there any way to get all the checkbox items with their values?

> [image]

I want to achieve something similar to the image above. If the item is checked, I show an icon; if the item is unchecked, another icon will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox values are preprocessed so only checked ones you can get in your twig:
I think you need to preprocess your field by implementing [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to add unchecked ones to your variables something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if ($element['#field_name'] == "field_room_category") {
    // Node object.
    $node = $element['#object'];
    // All allowed values in the field.
    $allowed_values = $node->field_room_category->getFieldDefinition()
      ->getSetting('allowed_values');

    // Checked values.
    $checked_values = array_filter($element, function ($key) {
      return is_int($key);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($allowed_values); $i++) {
      // If the checkbox already checked add is_selected as true.
      if (isset($checked_values[$i])) {
        $variables['element'][$i]['is_selected'] = TRUE;
      }
      else {
        // If the checkbox not checked add the item with is_selected as false.
        $variables['element'][$i] = [
          '#markup'       => current(array_slice($allowed_values, $i-1, 1, FALSE)),
          '#allowed_tags' => [],
          'is_selected'   => FALSE,
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now in your twig you can do something like:

```
  {% for key, item in element if key|first != '#' %}
     <li>
       {% if item.is_selected %}
         <span style="color: green;">  {{ item }} </span>
       {% else %}
         <span style="color: red;">  {{ item }} </span>
       {% endif %}
     </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have added the above function in mythemename.theme.php. Nothing changed, I have just put a print_r on  $variables['element']; and it shows empty, so its not even entering the if condition. This is the function name I have used `mytheme_preprocess_node__content_type_products` it is a custom content type. Any changes needed?